# Плавное появление кнопки при написании текста в textarea

Tags: jquery

Добрый вечер Ув. Знатоки помогите реализовать такую вещь:
Нужно чтоб в textarea когда пишешь появлялся див и когда нажимаешь мимо textarea он исчезал.

Заранее огромное спасибо)

Comment: @Денис Милюков, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea id="test" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<button style="display: none">Ok</button>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').on('keyup', function(){
        $('button').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#test').blur(function(){
        $('button').fadeOut();
    });
});
```